# Having problem clicking on element onlclick

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, onclick

I have an element

```
button type = "button" name="finishN" id = "finishN" class="bp" onmouseover="this.className = 'bp b ph'" onmouseout = "this.className = 'bp'" onclick = "oCV_NS_.promptAction('finish')" style>Finish</button>
```

The only element I can use in "onclick" because the other elements are the same for the other buttons on the page and id/name elements change with every page reload.

I tried CSS_Selector for onlcick and XPath but cannot get the driver to click the "Finish" button.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: try this xpath  `//button[@onclick="oCV_NS_.promptAction('finish')"]` what do you get with that? Can you paste the html of that button, copypaste from browser.

Comment: let me try it, I cannot copy past because the  path is on a stand alone computer, it only connects to Government sites

Comment: Please share your Selenium code and if possible the link to the page you are working on so we will be able to debug it

Comment: Unfortunately  the site is on a secure network and I am not able to share the link.  But I do appreciate everyone trying to help!